# replace what's between brackets with a value using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

i want to replace what's between brackets with the value stored in **a** :

i tried this but it doesn't work for the value of **a** that i have :

```
a=';;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=('
echo "abc0  zz 43242 [replace this text] name" | sed '/abc/ s/\[.*]/['"$a]"'/'
```

Any idea how i can make it work ?

i tried

```
a=';;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=('
echo "abc0  zz 43242 [replace this text] name" | sed '/abc/ s/\[.*]/['"$a]"'/'
```

i expect the value stored in **a** is placed in the text between brackets but instead i get an error:

```
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 36: option inconnue pour « s »
```

Comment: If the variable contains characters that are special to `sed`, you need to escape them by backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
kent$  a=';;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=('
kent$  echo "abc0  zz 43242 [replace this text] name" | sed "/abc/ s@\[.*\]@$a@"
abc0  zz 43242 ;;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=( name
```

If you cannot predict what character your `a` variable can contain, you can think in a different way. Your input follows this format:

```
aaa[bbb]ccc[ddd]eee
```

You can take `[` or `]` as the separator, and break the input string and concatenate the variable value:

```
aaa+$a+ccc+$a+eee
```

Of course, the `+$a` part isn't valid shell syntax. Just for showing the idea.

Awk can do that relatively easierly. If [..] doesn't sit at the beginning of the input, you can replace even-number fields with the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `bash`, you can do this with [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) instead of `sed`

The following code shows two variants to replace the text *between* the brackets or *including* the brackets.

```bash
a=';;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=('
b='abc0  zz 43242 [replace this text] name'
echo "${b/\[replace this text\]/$a}"
echo "${b/\[replace this text\]/[$a]}"
```

prints

```
abc0  zz 43242 ;;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=( name
abc0  zz 43242 [;;6n{|p~zaaaaaaUZkj/!iI)btreml=(] name
```